# identify on what widgets the fling gesture is detected?

Tags: android, gestures

MY Screen is filled with different group of buttons, and i implemented gestures for the entire view. How can i identify,  the buttons and these are considered as selected , fling gesture path across the buttons/widgets?

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution would be to hold a Rect object for each button. the rect would hold the position of the button on screen(x,y,width,height).

then, when the gesture is made and you get an [x,y] position, simply iterate over all the Rect objects and use the Rect.contains(x,y) method to know if the gesture is on a button position.